# Simple puppet task fails

Tags: puppet

I've noted that a simplistic puppet task (an empty file), is failing:

```
puppet apply init.pp
```

Results in

```
Error: Could not run: Could not retrieve facts for xxxxx: no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

I've changed the init.pp file to an *empty file*, and the error persists.

Are there any special requirements that puppet 3.4 requires for running puppet standalone deployments?

Comment: I completely uninstalled all puppet modules - this fixed the issue.  But its not clear why or how a module could corrupt a simple puppet apply run so badly.

Comment: Unfortunate - there was likely a lingering bug in some fact code from one of your modules. To find it, the `--trace` option would have yielded the necessary info.

Answer (score 0):

One simple fix (in the comment above) : Uninstalling puppet modules.  But I suspect that there is a "proper" fix to this... so this question is still open.